# How to apply a Window Function in Druid?

Tags: druid

I have a question regarding the Druid query. I am trying to write a SQL code, calculating a simple next event type:

```
event_type next_event_type
media_play recommendation_hit
```

I tried to use the usual sql query:

```
LEAD(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) as next_event
```

But I am getting an error :

```
No match found for function signature  LEAD(<CHARACTER>)
```

Is it possible to use Window Functions in Druid and if not, what are the alternatives?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this question is related to yours: https://groups.google.com/g/druid-user/c/5kbu34ONKTA/m/mPRjSl9PAgAJ?utm_medium=3Demail&utm_source=3Dfooter

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing (latest current Druid release is 24.0.1) window functions are not available in Druid.

Work is being done to add them https://github.com/apache/druid/pull/13458

Since the 25.0 release is already code-frozen I suspect that you will see the window function functionally in Druid 26.0